# WEKA-Connect ARFF file with PHP

Tags: php, weka, arff

Can anyone tell me how to connect ARFF file to a php web system?is there a way to read arff files using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

ARFF files are the format for the data mining library Weka, which is written in Java. Thus, the natural way of reading it is through the Java methods created for that task. Depending on your purpose, you could read it as a plain text file (makes no sense to me), or using Java code in you php application, if it is possible.

But Weka is for data mining programming in Java. Could you clarify your purpose for this task?

Comment: i'm developing a diagnose system by using Decison tree as data mining techniques,this is a web system used php and mysql,i'm stuck in coding part to connect decision tree to the system,

Comment: That's a different topic than merely a data mining task. I can't help much on web applications, only on the Java/Weka part.